# Clear Option Clash error

Tags: errors, memoir

I'm working with a template to create a course syllabus. The package requires an .sty file, which I have in the same folder. No matter what I try, I can't clear an error: "Option clash for package color" on line 53. I've read that this has something to do with a repeated package, but I can't figure out where that is. Any help appreciated. [The .sty file is below as well]

```
%
% 
%
\documentclass[11pt,article,oneside]{memoir}

%% Script-based version control (requires vc package)
% \input{vc}

\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{memoir-article-styles} % in latex-custom-kjh/needs-memoir

%% Choose font system. Comment out these lines if you are not using xelatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}

% Biblatex
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
            bibstyle=authoryear,
            citestyle=authoryear-comp,
            uniquename=false,
            hyperref=true,
            backend=biber, babel=hyphen, bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex}

%% Fix biblatex's odd preference for using In: by default.
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{}\intitlepunct}}}

%% Bibliography from http://kjhealy.github.com/socbibs/
\addbibresource{/Users/kjhealy/Documents/bibs/socbib.bib}

% Definitions
\def\myauthor{Kieran Healy}
\def\mytitle{Sociology 155: Organizations and Management}
\def\mysubtitle{Syllabus}
\def\mycopyright{\myauthor}
\def\mykeywords{}
\def\mybibliostyle{plain}
\def\mybibliocommand{}
\def\mysubtitle{}
\def\myaddress{276 Soc/Psych}
\def\myemail{kjhealy@soc.duke.edu}
\def\myweb{http://www.kieranhealy.org}
\def\myphone{660-5737}
\def\myaffiliation{\ \\Duke University}
\def\mykeywords{Sociology, Syllabus, Undergraduate, Organizations, Management}

%% Links
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[xetex,
colorlinks=true,
urlcolor=BrickRed,
plainpages=false,
   pdfpagelabels,
   bookmarksnumbered,
   pdftitle={\mytitle},
   pdfauthor={\myauthor},
   pdfkeywords={\mykeywords}
   ]{hyperref}

%% Uncomment to make a "DRAFT" watermark
% Page watermark
% \usepackage{type1cm,eso-pic}
% \makeatletter
% \AddToShipoutPicture{%
% \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth}%
% \setlength{\@tempdimc}{.5\paperheight}%
% \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}%
% \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){%
% \makebox(0,0){\rotatebox{45}{\textcolor[gray]{0.9}%
% {\fontsize{3cm}{3cm}\selectfont{Draft Only}}}}%
% Marginal Watermark
% \makebox(-100,-300){\rotatebox{45}{\textcolor[gray]{0.95}%
% {\fontsize{2cm}{2cm}\selectfont{}}}}
% \makebox(-500,-0){\rotatebox{90}{\textcolor[gray]{0.95}%
% {\fontsize{0.7cm}{0.7cm}\selectfont{}}}}
% }%
% }
% \makeatother

\begin{document}

%%% xelatex font choices
%\defaultfontfeatures{}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
% You will need to buy these fonts, change the names to fonts you own, or comment out if not using xelatex.
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text,Scale=0.8]{Pragmata}

%% blank label items; hanging bibs for text
%% Custom hanging indent for vita items
\def\ind{\hangindent=1 true cm\hangafter=1 \noindent}
\def\labelitemi{$\cdot$}
%\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{~}

% Make figures as wide as the margins
\setkeys{Gin}{width=1\textwidth}

\chapterstyle{article-2} % alternative styles are defined in latex-custom-kjh/needs-memoir/. Consider e.g.\chapterstyle{article-4}
\pagestyle{kjh}

\title{\mytitle}
\author{\myauthor\smallskip\footnotesize\newline Office: 276 Sociology/Psychology \newline\texttt{\myemail} \newline \url{http://www.kieranhealy.org}}
\date{}

\published{\sffamily Spring 2010 / Tu\&Th 1:15--2:30pm / Gray 228}

\maketitle

% Include version information in footer if using vc package (see above).
% \thispagestyle{kjhgit}


% Copyright Page
% \textcopyright{} \mycopyright

%
% Main Content
%

\section{Course Description and Objectives}

%\newpage
%% Uncomment if you want a printed bibliography.
%\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Style file:

```
%%% Some article styles and page layout tweaks for the memoir class
%%% Choose these as article or pagestyles for your memoir document. 
%%% Kieran Healy


%%% --------------------------------------------------
%%% Some useful bits and pieces
%%% --------------------------------------------------
%% Blank footnote command.
% Use \symbolfootnote[0]{Footnote text} for a blank footnote. 
% Useful for an initial acknowledgment note.
\long\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{\begingroup%
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote[#1]{#2}\endgroup}

%% Redefine \and and \andnext to remove tabular environment.
%% Needed below for custom article-styles when multiple authors are present. 
\renewcommand{\and}{\, }
\renewcommand*{\andnext}{%
  \\\medskip }

%%% --------------------------------------------------
%%% Style: memo-comments
%%% For short notes.
%%% --------------------------------------------------

% Make the style for Chapters and sections
   \makechapterstyle{memo-comments}{
     \renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} 
     \setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily} 
     \setsubsecheadstyle{\large\sffamily} 
     \setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\sffamily\itshape} 
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{} 
    \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{} 
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont} 
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter\space} 
    \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{} 
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\secheadstyle}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont} 
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont\sffamily} 
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{\sffamily} 
    %\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{} 
    %\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
    \captiontitlefont{\small}
    \settocdepth{chapter}
    \maxsecnumdepth{chapter} 
    \setsecnumdepth{chapter}

    % reduce skip after section heading
    \setaftersecskip{1.7ex}

    % Title 
    \pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}
    \posttitle{\end{flushleft}\par\vskip 0.5em}
    \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\Large\sffamily}
    \postauthor{\end{flushleft}}
    \predate{\begin{flushleft}\sffamily\footnotesize\vspace{0.9em}}
    \postdate{\end{flushleft}\par\vskip 2em}
   }

%%% --------------------------------------------------
%%% Style: article-1 
%%% --------------------------------------------------
   \makechapterstyle{article-1}{
     \setsecheadstyle{\Large\scshape} 
     \setsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\itshape} 
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{} 
    \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{} 
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont} 
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter\space} 
    \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{} 
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\secheadstyle}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont} 
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont\scshape} 
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{\scshape} 
    %\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{} 
    %\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
    \captiontitlefont{\small}
    %\settocdepth{chapter}
%     \maxsecnumdepth{section} 
%     \setsecnumdepth{section}

    % reduce skip after section heading
    \setaftersecskip{1.7ex}

    % set name of bibliography to 'references'
    % \renewcommand{\bibname}{\mdseries\Large\scshape\MakeLowercase References}

    \pretitle{\newline\centering \LARGE\scshape \MakeLowercase }
    \posttitle{\par\vskip 1em}
    \predate{\footnotesize \centering}
    \postdate{\par\vskip 1em}

    % 'abstract' title, bigger skip from title
    \addto\captionsamerican{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}}
    \abstractrunin
   }

%%% --------------------------------------------------
%%% Style: article-2 
%%% --------------------------------------------------

% Make the style for Chapters and sections
   \makechapterstyle{article-2}{
    \setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily} 
    \setsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\sffamily\itshape} 
    \setaftersubsubsecskip{-1em}
    \setsubsubsecheadstyle{\small\bfseries}
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{} 
    \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{} 
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont} 
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter\space} 
    \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{} 
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\secheadstyle}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont} 
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont\scshape} 
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{\scshape} 
    %\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{} 
    %\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
    \captiontitlefont{\small}
    %\settocdepth{chapter}
    \maxsecnumdepth{chapter} 
    \setsecnumdepth{chapter}

    % reduce skip after section heading
    \setaftersecskip{1.7ex}

    % set name of bibliography to 'references'
    % \renewcommand{\bibname}{\mdseries\Large\scshape\MakeLowercase References}

    % Title flush left
    \pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE\sffamily}
    \posttitle{\end{flushleft}\par\vskip 0.5em}
    \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\sffamily\itshape  \Large \vspace{0.5em}}
    \postauthor{\end{flushleft}}
    \predate{\begin{flushleft}\sffamily\footnotesize\vspace{0.9em}}
    \postdate{\end{flushleft}\par\vskip 2em}

    % 'abstract' title, bigger skip from title
    \addto\captionsamerican{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract:}}
    \renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\scriptsize\itshape}
    \renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\scriptsize}
    \abstractrunin

   }

%%% --------------------------------------------------
%%% Style: article-3 
%%% --------------------------------------------------

% Make the style for Chapters and sections
   \makechapterstyle{article-3}{
     \renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} 
     \setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily} 
     \setsubsecheadstyle{\large\sffamily} 
     \setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\sffamily\itshape} 
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{} 
    \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{} 
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont} 
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter\space} 
    \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{} 
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\secheadstyle}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont} 
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont\sffamily} 
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{\sffamily} 
    %\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{} 
    %\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
    \captiontitlefont{\small}
    \settocdepth{chapter}
    \maxsecnumdepth{chapter} 
    \setsecnumdepth{chapter}

    % reduce skip after section heading
    \setaftersecskip{1.7ex}

    % set name of bibliography to 'references'
    % \renewcommand{\bibname}{\mdseries\Large\sffamily\MakeLowercase References}

    % Title 
    \pretitle{\par\vskip 3em 
        \begin{flushleft}\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}
    \posttitle{\end{flushleft}\par\vskip 0.5em}
    \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\Large\bigskip}
    \postauthor{\end{flushleft}}
    \predate{\begin{flushleft}\normalsize}
    \postdate{\end{flushleft}}

    % \pretitle{\LARGE \sffamily}
    % \posttitle{\par\vskip 0.5em}
    % \preauthor{\large \sffamily \lineskip 1em}
    % \postauthor{\par\lineskip 1em}
    % \predate{\sffamily\footnotesize\vspace{0.65em}}
    % \postdate{\par\vskip 2em}

    % 'abstract' title, bigger skip from title
    \addto\captionsamerican{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract:}}
    \renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\scriptsize\itshape}
    \renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\scriptsize}
    \abstractrunin

   }     

%%% --------------------------------------------------
%%% Style: article-4 (AJS) 
%%% --------------------------------------------------

%% Make the style for Chapters and sections
   \makechapterstyle{article-4}{
    \setsecheadstyle{\Large\scshape\MakeLowercase} 
    \setsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\itshape} 
    \setaftersubsubsecskip{-1em}
    \setsubsubsecheadstyle{\small\bfseries}
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{} 
    \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{} 
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont} 
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter\space} 
    \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{} 
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\secheadstyle}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont} 
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont\scshape} 
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{\scshape} 
    %\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{} 
    %\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
    \captiontitlefont{\small}
    %\settocdepth{chapter}
    \maxsecnumdepth{chapter} 
    \setsecnumdepth{chapter}

    % reduce skip after section heading
    \setaftersecskip{1.7ex}

    % set name of bibliography to 'references'
    %\renewcommand{\bibname}{\mdseries\Large\scshape\MakeLowercase References}

    % % Title flush left
    \pretitle{\par\vskip 3em 
        \begin{flushleft}\LARGE\bfseries}
    \posttitle{\end{flushleft}\par\vskip 0.5em}
    \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\normalsize\bigskip}
    \postauthor{\end{flushleft}}
    \predate{\begin{flushleft}\normalsize}
    \postdate{\end{flushleft}}

    % 'abstract' bigger skip from title
    \addto\captionsamerican{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}}
    \renewcommand{\abstractname}{}
    \renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\scriptsize}
    \abstractrunin
   }


%%% --------------------------------------------------
%%% article-4-sans (AJS, but sans-serif headings) 
%%% --------------------------------------------------

%% Make the style for Chapters and sections
   \makechapterstyle{article-4-sans}{
    \setsecheadstyle{\sffamily\bfseries} 
    \setsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\sffamily\itshape} 
    \setaftersubsubsecskip{-1em}
    \setsubsubsecheadstyle{\small}
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{} 
    \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{} 
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont} 
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter\space} 
    \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{} 
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\secheadstyle}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont} 
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont\sffamily} 
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{\sffamily} 
    %\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{} 
    %\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
    \captiontitlefont{\small}
    %\settocdepth{chapter}
    \maxsecnumdepth{chapter} 
    \setsecnumdepth{chapter}

    %% reduce skip after section heading
    \setaftersecskip{1.7ex}

    %% set name of bibliography to 'references'
    %%\renewcommand{\bibname}{\mdseries\Large\sffamily References}

    % % Title flush left
    \pretitle{\par\vskip 3em 
        \begin{flushleft}\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}
    \posttitle{\end{flushleft}\par\vskip 0.5em}
    \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\Large}
    \postauthor{\end{flushleft}}
    \predate{\begin{flushleft}\normalsize}
    \postdate{\end{flushleft}}

    %% 'abstract' bigger skip from title
    \addto\captionsamerican{\renewcommand*{\abstractname}{}}
    \renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\scriptsize}
    \renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\scriptsize}
    \abstractrunin


   }

%%% --------------------------------------------------
%%% Style: membook
%%% A book style
%%% --------------------------------------------------

%% Make the style for Chapters and sections
   % \makechapterstyle{membook}{
   %  \setsecheadstyle{\Large\sffamily\bfseries} 
   %  \setsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\sffamily\itshape} 
   %      \setaftersubsubsecskip{-1em}
   %  \setsubsubsecheadstyle{\small\sffamily\bfseries}
   %  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\sffamily} 
   %  \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{\sffamily} 
   %  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont\sffamily} 
   %  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter\space} 
   %  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{} 
   %  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\secheadstyle}
   %  \renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont} 
   %  \renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont\sffamily} 
   %  \renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{\sffamily} 
   %  \renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\sffamily} 
   %  \renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
   %  \captiontitlefont{\small}
   %  %\settocdepth{chapter}
   %  \maxsecnumdepth{chapter} 
   %  \setsecnumdepth{chapter}

   %  % reduce skip after section heading
   %  \setaftersecskip{1.7ex}

   %  % set name of bibliography to 'references'
   %  %\renewcommand{\bibname}{\mdseries\Large\scshape\MakeLowercase References}

   %  % % Title flush left
   %  \pretitle{\par\vskip 3em 
   %      \begin{flushleft}\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}
   %  \posttitle{\end{flushleft}\par\vskip 0.5em}
   %  \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\normalsize\sffamily\bigskip}
   %  \postauthor{\end{flushleft}}
   %  \predate{\begin{flushleft}\normalsize\sffamily}
   %  \postdate{\end{flushleft}}

   %  % 'abstract' bigger skip from title
   %  \addto\captionsamerican{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}}
   %  \renewcommand{\abstractname}{}
   %  \renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\scriptsize}
   %  \abstractrunin
   % }


%\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
%\RequirePackage{calc}
%\RequirePackage{color,calc}
%\newsavebox{\ChpNumBox}
%\definecolor{ChapBlue}{rgb}{0.00,0.65,0.65}
%\makeatletter
% \newcommand*{\thickhrulefill}{%
%   \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 1\p@ \hfill \kern \z@}
% \newcommand*\BuildChpNum[2]{%
%   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
%     \makebox[0pt][c]{#1\strut}  \\[.5ex]
%     \colorbox{BrickRed}{%
%       \rule[-10em]{0pt}{0pt}%
%       \rule{1ex}{0pt}\color{black}#2\strut
%       \rule{1ex}{0pt}}%
%   \end{tabular}}
% \makechapterstyle{BlueBox}{%
%   \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\large\sffamily}
%   \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\Huge\sffamily}
%   \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\raggedright\Huge\sffamily}
%   \setlength{\beforechapskip}{20pt}
%   \setlength{\midchapskip}{26pt}
%   \setlength{\afterchapskip}{40pt}
%   \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\sffamily}
%   \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{\sffamily}
%   \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
%     \sbox{\ChpNumBox}{%
%       \BuildChpNum{\chapnamefont\@chapapp}%
%       {\chapnumfont\thechapter}}}
%   \renewcommand{\printchapternonum}{%
%     \sbox{\ChpNumBox}{%
%       \BuildChpNum{\chapnamefont\vphantom{\@chapapp}}%
%       {\chapnumfont\hphantom{\thechapter}}}}
% \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
% \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
%   \usebox{\ChpNumBox}\hfill
%   \parbox[t]{\hsize-\wd\ChpNumBox-1em}{%
%     \vspace{\midchapskip}%
%     \thickhrulefill\par
%     \chaptitlefont ##1\par}}%
%     \pretitle{\par\vskip 3em 
%         \begin{flushleft}\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}
%     \posttitle{\end{flushleft}\par\vskip 0.5em}
%     \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\normalsize\sffamily\bigskip}
%     \postauthor{\end{flushleft}}
%     \predate{\begin{flushleft}\normalsize}
%     \postdate{\end{flushleft}}

% }


%%% -------------------------------------------------- 
%%% Custom styles for headers and footers The chapterstyles above
%%% style sections/subsections and titles, etc. These pagestyles
%%% control the running headers and footers. So far there's just one.
%%% --------------------------------------------------

%%%
%%% Basic 
%%%
\makepagestyle{kjh}
%\makeevenfoot{kjh}{\thepage}{}{}
%\makeoddfoot{kjh}{}{}{\thepage}
%\makeheadrule{kjh}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\newcommand{\@kjhmarks}{%
  \let\@mkboth\markboth
  \def\chaptermark##1{%
    \markboth{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
          \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
      \fi
      ##1}{}}
  \def\sectionmark##1{%
    \markright{##1}}
}
\makepsmarks{kjh}{\@kjhmarks}
\makepsmarks{kjh}{}
\makeevenhead{kjh}{}{}{\scshape\thepage}
\makeoddhead{kjh}{}{}{\scshape\thepage}



%%%
%%% RCS in footer 
%%%

% Make the style for RCS revision control headers and footers
\makepagestyle{kjhrcs}
% \makeheadrule{kjhrcs}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\newcommand{\@kjhrcsmarks}{%
  \let\@mkboth\markboth
  \def\chaptermark##1{%
    \markboth{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
          \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
      \fi
      ##1}{}}
  \def\sectionmark##1{%
    \markright{##1}}
}
\makepsmarks{kjhrcs}{\@kjhrcsmarks}
%\makeevenhead{kjhrcs}{\footnotesize\scshape\leftmark}{}{\scshape\thepage}
%\makeoddhead{kjhrcs}{}{}{\footnotesize\rightmark\normalsize\ \ \scshape\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{kjhrcs}{\texttt{\footnotesize\rcsInfoFile}}{\scshape\thepage}{\footnotesize \emph{Rev} \texttt{\rcsInfoRevision \  \rcsInfoDate}}
\makeoddfoot{kjhrcs}{\texttt{\footnotesize\rcsInfoFile}}{\scshape\thepage}{\footnotesize \emph{Rev} \texttt{\rcsInfoRevision \ \rcsInfoDate}}



%%%
%%% Mercurial rev info in footers 
%%%

% Make the style for hg revision control headers and footers
\makepagestyle{kjhhg}
% \makeheadrule{kjhhg}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\newcommand{\@kjhhgmarks}{%
  \let\@mkboth\markboth
  \def\chaptermark##1{%
    \markboth{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
          \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
      \fi
      ##1}{}}
  \def\sectionmark##1{%
    \markright{##1}}
}
\makepsmarks{kjhhg}{\@kjhhgmarks}
%\makeevenhead{kjhhg}{\footnotesize\scshape\leftmark}{}{\scshape\thepage}
%\makeoddhead{kjhhg}{}{}{\footnotesize\rightmark\normalsize\ \ \scshape\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{kjhhg}{\texttt{\footnotesize \hgkw{Filename}}}{\scshape\thepage}{\texttt{\footnotesize Rev \hgkw{LastChangedRevision} on \hgfilemonth\ \hgfileday, \hgfileyear}}
\makeoddfoot{kjhhg}{\texttt{\footnotesize \hgkw{Filename}}}{\scshape\thepage}{\texttt{\footnotesize Rev \hgkw{LastChangedRevision} on \hgfilemonth\ \hgfileday, \hgfileyear}}



%%%
%%% Git info in footers; requires vc package 
%%%

% Make the style for vc-git revision control headers and footers
\makepagestyle{kjhgit}
% \makeheadrule{kjhgit}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\newcommand{\@kjhgitmarks}{%
  \let\@mkboth\markboth
  \def\chaptermark##1{%
    \markboth{%
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \if@mainmatter
          \thechapter. \ %
        \fi
      \fi
      ##1}{}}
  \def\sectionmark##1{%
    \markright{##1}}
}
\makepsmarks{kjhgit}{\@kjhgitmarks}
%\makeevenhead{kjhgit}{\footnotesize\scshape\leftmark}{}{\scshape\thepage}
%\makeoddhead{kjhgit}{}{}{\footnotesize\rightmark\normalsize\ \ \scshape\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{kjhgit}{}{\scshape\thepage}{\texttt{\footnotesize \VCRevision\ on \VCDateTEX}}
\makeoddfoot{kjhgit}{}{\scshape\thepage}{\texttt{\footnotesize \VCRevision\ on \VCDateTEX}}            

%%% 
%%% Custom appendix 
%%%

% % Make the style for headers and footers in the Appendix
% \makepagestyle{kjhappendix}
% %\makeevenfoot{kjh}{\thepage}{}{}
% %\makeoddfoot{kjh}{}{}{\thepage}
% \makeheadrule{kjhapp}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
% \newcommand{\@kjhappmarks}{%
%   \let\@mkboth\markboth
%   \def\chaptermark##1{%
%     \markboth{%
%       \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
%         \if@mainmatter
%           \thechapter. \ %
%         \fi
%       \fi
%       ##1}{}}
%   \def\sectionmark##1{%
%     \markright{##1}}
% }
% \makepsmarks{kjhappendix}{\@kjhappmarks}
% \makeevenhead{kjhappendix}{\footnotesize\scshape Appendix}{}{\scshape\thepage}
% \makeoddhead{kjhappendix}{}{}{\footnotesize Data and Methods for \rightmark\normalsize\ \ \scshape\thepage}

%% Create a command to make a note at the top of the first page describing the
%% publication status of the paper. 
\newcommand{\published}[1]{% 
   \gdef\puB{#1}} 
   \newcommand{\puB}{} 
   \renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{% 
       \par\noindent\footnotesize \puB} 

\endinput
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I try your example I don't get any error.

Comment: Hm. That's weird.

Comment: Since I do not have those fonts I am having problem reproducing your errors. A smaller example that is easier to get to run would be helpful. I have had option clashes with memoir because memoir loads a lot of packages by itself. I think it is possible to give the option to memoir which will hand it on to the package but to do that you need to know which option is clashing...

Comment: For me this is fine with an up to date TL. I have some idea what might be up but would need a `.log` file to be sure.